# How can I see the execution plan for stored procedures and triggers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can I see the execution plan for stored procedures and triggers in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can using SQL Profiler. See [Using SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
set showplan_text on
```

or hit CTRL + K and it will be included as a separate tab next to query results

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MSSQL, yes, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190233.aspx)